# How to get gzip encoded content from hotelbeds apitude PHP API

Tags: php, gzip, pecl

Recently, I started working with [Hotelbeds APITUDE PHP API](https://developer.hotelbeds.com/)

I am trying to send request and get response through [pecl_http](https://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http)

Now I am facing some problems with getting gzip encoding data through the API. Here are endpoint and headers [information](https://developer.hotelbeds.com/docs/read/Hotel_Endpoints_and_Headers)

I am trying with following code -

```
$xml_part = <<< EOD
                <availabilityRQ xmlns="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/messages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" dailyRate="true">
                <stay checkIn="2016-09-15" checkOut="2016-09-16"/>
                <occupancies>
                <occupancy rooms="1" adults="2" children="0">
                <paxes>
                <pax type="AD"/>
                <pax type="AD"/>
                </paxes>
                </occupancy>
                </occupancies>
                <hotels>
                <hotel>1067</hotel>
                <hotel>1070</hotel>
                </hotels>
                <keywords>
                <keyword>34</keyword>
                <keyword>38</keyword>
                <keyword>100</keyword>
                </keywords>
                <boards included="true">
                <board>RO</board>
                <board>BB</board>
                </boards>
                <rooms included="TRUE">
                <room>DBT.ST</room>
                </rooms>
                <accommodations>
                <accommodation>HOTEL</accommodation>
                <accommodation>HOSTEL</accommodation>
                </accommodations>
                <reviews>
                <review type="TRIPADVISOR" maxRate="5" minReviewCount="3"/>
                </reviews>
                <filter minRate="100.000" maxRate="170.000"/>
                <filter minCategory="3" maxCategory="5"/>
                <filter paymentType="AT_HOTEL"/>
                <filter maxRatesPerRoom="3"/>
                <filter packaging="TRUE"/>
                <filter hotelPackage="YES"/>
                <filter maxRooms="2"/>
                </availabilityRQ> EOD;

$endpoint = "https://api.test.hotelbeds.com/hotel-api/1.0/hotels";

                $body = new http\Message\Body();

                $body->append($xml_part);

                $request = new http\Client\Request("POST",
                    $endpoint,
                    ["Api-Key" => $hotel_beds_config['api_key'],
                        "X-Signature" => $signature,
                        "Content-Type" => "application/xml",
                        "Accept" => "application/xml",
                        "Accept-encoding" => "Gzip"
                    ],
                    $body
                );

                try {

                    $client = new http\Client;

                    $client->enqueue($request)->send();

                    $response = $client->getResponse();

                    if ($response->getResponseCode() != 200) {

                        printf($response->getBody());

                    } else {
                        echo '<pre>';
                        printf(json_encode($response->getBody()));
                        echo gzencode(json_encode($response->getBody()));
                        echo '</pre>';

                    }

                } catch (Exception $ex) {

                    printf("Error while sending request, reason: %s\n", $ex->getMessage());

                }
```

I get 200 response code when make a API request. All I am facing problem with retrieving data from response body. In the output I see like following encoded data -

> {}���C���

How can I get gzip encoded data as request content body?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `pecl_http` but I see two problems with your code:

**1.** This line:

```
    </availabilityRQ> EOD;
```

Should be replaced with

```
    </availabilityRQ> 
EOD;
```

The end-delimiter `EOD;` must be by itself on a line; no other character, not even empty space is allowed before or after it.

**2.** If the response you get is correctly gzip encoded, then these lines don't make much sense:

```
printf(json_encode($response->getBody()));
echo gzencode(json_encode($response->getBody()));
```

You never try to decode the response; In fact you're trying to `json_encode` it!  Try instead

```
$gz_encoded = $response->getBody();
$gz_decoded = gzdecode($gz_encoded);
```

Now you can examine the result. If it's a JSON string, you can decode it:

```
$final_str = json_decode($gz_decoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

You manually set the "Accept-Encoding: gzip" header, so your response is probably gzip encoded, and thus the former poster is right.

Avoid this by removing the explicit header and tell the client to hande gzip encoded content with `$client->setOptions(["compress" => true]);`.